# How did a marriage officially commence among Hebrew people 2000 years ago?

Tags: history, marriage

About 2 thousand years ago how was a new marriage registered among Hebrew people? Was it registered at all? How did a man and a woman officially become married? Was it just a kind of public announcement and a feast, after which it would be absolutely legal for them to start living together or did they have to somehow "authenticate" their marriage at the synagogue, perhaps, with the help of a priest?

(Please, note that this question is different from [another question of mine](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17686/how-did-a-virgin-decide-upon-her-marriage-in-israel-2000-years-ago) on marriage that I asked 2 years ago)

Comment: I don't know about "official" registration with the "authorities", but the ketuba/marriage contract was a crucial part of the process. Several marriage contracts from the late 1st century/early 2nd century were found in the Dead Sea area...the contract wording is VERY similar to today's, amazingly enough. I don't have any handy links for you, but googling "Babatha archive" should get you to a translation/facsimile of one set of them.

Comment: @Gary, a _k'suba_ is a prenup.

Comment: @msh210 - okay, sorry!  It didn't seem to have much of a "pre" part to it for us--we looked it over and signed it with the witnesses just before the ceremony--I thought it was the "official wedding contract".  When the wife growls or jokes n points to it on the wall it doesn't seem to be much a  "pre" thing either....more like a binding contract, with me being the bound one...

Answer (score 6):

Jewish law dictates that there be a marriage ceremony. The ceremony entails *erusin*, also known as *kidushin*, and *nisuin*. The former designates the wife to the husband and the latter starts their life together. This was true two millennia ago and remains true today. See e.g. [Wikipedia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_wedding) or [Judaism 101](http://www.jewfaq.org/marriage.htm#Kiddushin).

Answer (score 6):

Another answer addressed how marriages became officialized. The question also asked about registration, so I'll address that.

There was no official registration of a marriage. There were various forms of testimony which could be used to substantiate the claim that a man and woman were married, such as the marriage document (kesuba), witnesses of the engagement (kiddushin) [[Isurei Biah 1:23](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=5&hilchos=27&perek=1&halocha=23)]or marriage (nisuin) ceremonies, or even witnesses that they had been living together and conducting themselves as husband and wife ([Isuri Biah 1:21](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=5&hilchos=27&perek=1&halocha=21)). However, there was no central list of marriages that one could consult to check if someone was married.